# how to ensure equal spacing in styling?

Tags: css

I am trying to style my text in such a way that I can ensure equal spacing within text. While I am able to achieve this (somewhat), I don't feel like I can control the spacing as much as I want.

Is there a way I can do the current styling better?

```html
<ul class="hcenter">
            <li class="inline tcenter w25"><b>Text</b></li>
            <li class="inline tcenter w25"><b>TextA</b></li>
            <li class="inline tcenter w25"><b>TextB</b></li>
            <li class="inline tcenter w25"><b>TextC</b></li>
    </ul>
```

The output is like this

> Text TextA TextB TextC

what I want to do is increase the spacing between the words.

Comment: did you try setting some padding to your <li> elements?

Comment: Currently it looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwvdz1ow/

Comment: Reading your description, I have to ask: What are you actually trying to achieve? If it's just word spacing, there's a css property for that.

Comment: did you mean space between TextA and TextB?

Comment: yes, that's what i meant

Answer (score 0):

You can achieved it by putting equal padding

```css
li{float:left; list-style-type:none; padding:5px 10px;}
```

```html
<ul class="hcenter">
        <li class="inline tcenter w25"><b>Text</b></li>
        <li class="inline tcenter w25"><b>TextA</b></li>
        <li class="inline tcenter w25"><b>TextB</b></li>
        <li class="inline tcenter w25"><b>TextC</b></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, pretty close, though the width control is limited. What more can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this:

```
<ul class="hcenter">
    <li class="inline tcenter w25"><b>Text</b></li>
    <li class="inline tcenter w25"><b>TextA</b></li>
    <li class="inline tcenter w25"><b>TextB</b></li>
    <li class="inline tcenter w25"><b>TextC</b></li>
```

CSS:

```
.hcenter > li
{
  padding : 15px;
  width: 25px;
}
```

or try this:

```
.tcenter
 {
  padding : 10px;
  width: 20px;
 }
```

Comment: this one results in TextC being displaced above the others

Answer (score 0):

I've created working solution for this. https://jsfiddle.net/rspb1843/
Looks like you should use this code.

```css
.hcenter {
  display: table;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 0;
  /*Remove default UL padding*/
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.hcenter li {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Example 2 */

.hcenter2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 500px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0;
  /*Remove default UL padding*/
}
.hcenter2 li {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```